# Working with multiple forms in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have several models - `Node`, `Link`, and `Map`. Map has `link_id`, `node_a_id`, and `node_b_id` fields. I am displaying a single form for `Link`, and 2 for `Node`. How do I save the entered information in the `Map` model which will store the relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using ModelForms, and that the map needs the link and nodes to be saved.

So first you need to save this models and then save the map-model. I'll also assume, that link_id, node_a_id and node_b_id are defined as models.ForeignKey(Link)...

So it would look somthing like this:

```
# somehwere on your views.py ...

def my_display_forms_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        na = Node()
        nb = Node()
        link = Link()
        na_form = NodeForm(request.POST, instance=na)
        nb_form = NodeForm(request.POST, instance=nb)
        link_form = LinkForm(request.POST, instance=link)

        if na_form.is_valid() and nb_form.is_valid() and link_form.is_valid():
            na = na_form.save()
            nb = nb_form.save()
            link = link_form.save()
            map = Map(link_id=link, node_a_id=na, node_b_id=nb)
            # maybe here fill more fields for map
            map.save()
            # eventually do some more stuff
    else:
       ... generate new unbound forms here
    return render_to_response(...)
```